# how to make while loop work not once? java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

Could someone help me?
I'm studying java and have such code:

```
   //...
        for (int i = 0; i < player.length; i++) {
            Player d = player[i];
            Object chose;
            do {
                String chosenplayer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose a player:");
                System.out.println("you chose player: " + chosenplayer);
                chose = chosenplayer;

            } while (!d.getPlayerName().equals(chose)) {
                if (d.getPlayerTalon() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("name=" + d.getPlayerName() + " talon=" + d.getPlayerTalon());
                    d.setFreeTalons();
                }
            }
        }
```

I need a "while loop": when `(!d.getPlayerName().equals(chose))` and `(d.getPlayerTalon()>0).` loop works till `d.getPlayerTalon()>0`

but now the program stops after first circle of `(!d.getPlayerName().equals(chose))` but I need such many circles with `(!d.getPlayerName().equals(chose))` till `d.getPlayerTalon()>0`

**there is 3 players in a team, each player has 10 tickets, For example I would like to choose player#1 and take one ticket from him - so now he has 9 tickets, after that I would like to check again is a player#1 in the team? if there is such player I would to check has he a tickets, if yes, - take one more ticket, so the player#1 will have 8 tickets, and so on.**

Sorry for my explanation, but I do my best to explain it.

Comment: Please... format your code. My eyes are bleeding

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to do it, I'm a tyro.

Comment: A tyro ? What do you mean ?

Comment: Format the code is just respecting the indentation. If you have a space bar on your keyboard you can do it :)

Comment: You need to change your loop condition (the one you have in braces). When it evaluates to false -- loop stops. You may also use break; statement.

Comment: ...... why do you have a `do {} while();` look, and then an opening `{` after that `while`? Please read about control statements here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: I have deleted a braces after `while();`  but it doesn't helps

Comment: there is 3 players in a team, each player has 10 tickets, For example I would like to choose player#1 and take one ticket from him - so now he has 9 tickets, after that I would like to check again is a player#1 in the team? if there is such player I would to check has he a tickets, if yes, - take one more ticket, so the player#1 will have 8 tickets, and so on.

Comment: I think I need add one more comparison to the loop. Something like this: `while (!d.getDoctorName().equals(chose)) &&(d.getDoctorTalon() > 0) `but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < player.length; i++) {
            Player d = player[i];
            String chose;
            do {
                String chosenplayer = JOptionPane
                        .showInputDialog("Please choose a player:");
                System.out.println("you chose player: " + chosenplayer);
                chose = chosenplayer;

            } while (!d.getPlayerName().equals(chose));
            if (d.getPlayerTalon() > 0) {
                System.out.println("name=" + d.getPlayerName() + " talon="
                        + d.getPlayerTalon());
                d.setFreeTalons();
            }

        }
    }

Use this code.
```

Comment: how is the behavior now?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 blocks in your code - one is the do-while loop, the other is this:

```
       { 
         if (d.getPlayerTalon()>0){
               System.out.println (...);
             d.setFreeTalons();
          }
       }
```

Yes, you can have blocks without control structures associated with them in Java, hope this clarifies it a bit.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand your answer

Comment: do-while loop should be terminated with `;` The block mentioned in the answer is not associated with the loop and does not need be enclosed as a block at all (remove the enclosing `{  }`